# Limit of sequence of multiple integrals

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_{[0,1]^n}\frac{x_1^5+\ldots+x_n^5}{x_1^4+\ldots+x_n^4}dx_1\dots dx_n$$

Comment: Please give more context to this problem, such as where you saw it and your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: I don't understand why this is being voted to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. I suggest making use of the integral identity
$$\int _{t=0}^{t=\infty} e^{- t ( x_1 ^4 + \ldots x_n ^4)} dt = \frac{ 1}{  x_1 ^4 + \ldots x_n ^4}$$

and then reversing the order of integration with respect to time and space variables.